# Load Qt CSS into Qt designer for an useful preview?

Tags: css, qt, qt-designer

Already in the planning phase of our application it has been decided that CSS styles are to be loaded externally from files. That's done like this:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
// Some QWidget overload
MainMenu menu;
// Load from resource (qrc file)
QFile css_file(":/black_style.css");
css_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString css = QLatin1String(css_file.readAll());
app.setStyleSheet(css);

menu.show();
```

The problem is this means that when creating the program in designer, I no longer have any notion what is it gonna look like. Can I load the stylesheet into designer without actually applying it onto the `ui` file?

Comment: Well, what about a lazy solution which is to put all the css file in comments ?

Comment: No, that's the exact opposite - I don't wanna discard the CSS file data. Because it affects multiple forms (when you apply style on `QApplication` it seems to have global effect). I need to see what it looks like with that CSS file.